# How to access users data based on username?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I'm still new in java and firebase and I'm currently try to play around with firebase.

I have this database in Firebase and I would like to be able to access all the data from the child node base on the username.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "lecturers" : {
      "MqTxiHdiwwNZwubExEzGMRG7FN93" : {
        "email" : "c@c.com",
        "password" : "123456",
        "username" : "c"
      }
    },
    "students" : {
      "XPTDRuIGXtZLCfYc8v89Me00NQ22" : {
        "email" : "a@c.com",
        "password" : "123456",
        "username" : "a"
      },
      "Y8DewhUpWUTp7yYjWmp1IOikmhu2" : {
        "email" : "b@c.com",
        "password" : "123456",
        "username" : "b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do exactly is, read all the data from users node with the role of 'students' or 'lecturers' which what I have tried.... (because I would like to pass the username value to other functions)

```
public User uInfo = new User();  //declaring as global variable
public String usrs;   //declaring as global variable

public String goTo(){
  String usr = uInfo.getUsername();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 2: "+ usrs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return  usr;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

  String role = sharedPreferences.getString(ROLE, "");
  Toast.makeText(this, "Role:  " + role, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Log.d("TESTT", "Role:  " + role);

  // Read from the database
  databaseReference.child("users").child(role).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
          String usersID = user.getUid();    
          uInfo.setUsername(dataSnapshot.child(usersID).getValue(User.class).getUsername());

          usrs = uInfo.getUsername();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1: "+ usrs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          // Failed to read value
          Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
      }
  });
}
```

But the code that I did only access username value from the current user that is currently login to the apps.

What I would like to do next is to compare the username from the list of users in the database and invoke another functions. Where, currently there is no user login to the system.

```
public void goTo(String username ){
   String usr = uInfo.getUsername(); //Not sure if this correct way 
   String email = uInfo.getEmail();  //Not sure if this correct way 
   String passowrd= uInfo.getPassword();  //Not sure if this correct way 

   if(usr.equals(username)){
       //do something
       //pass(email, password);
   }

}

public void pass(String email, String passwords ){
   //Do something with email and password variable that is passed

}
```

But I'm not sure what I should do in this part of the coding

```
// Read from the database
  databaseReference.child("users").child(role).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          //WHat should i change here?
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          // Failed to read value
          Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
      }
  });
```

This is my User.java

```
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if the question is too long. I already tried to search for solution in stackoverflow but I did not find any answer for my problem (or I have weak googling skills T-T). Can you guys help point me to the right directions. I've stuck with this problem for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firebase Database query returns child nodes directly under the location where you execute that query. You cannot run a single query across multiple locations. So there's no way to have a single query for the username that runs across both `/users/lecturers` and`/users/students`.

But I have a feeling that your user names are meant to be unique. In that case, the common solution is to keep a separate node in your database that maps user names to UIDs.

```
"user_names": {
  "a": "XPTDRuIGXtZLCfYc8v89Me00NQ22",
  "b": "Y8DewhUpWUTp7yYjWmp1IOikmhu2",
  "c": "MqTxiHdiwwNZwubExEzGMRG7FN93"
}
```

In your case, I'd keep the *path* to the user in the value:

```
"user_names": {
  "a": "students/XPTDRuIGXtZLCfYc8v89Me00NQ22",
  "b": "students/Y8DewhUpWUTp7yYjWmp1IOikmhu2",
  "c": "lecturers/MqTxiHdiwwNZwubExEzGMRG7FN93"
}
```

And now you *can* look up the user from a name with a simply double read:

```
databaseReference.child("user_names").child(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String path = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      DatabaseReference userRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(path);
      ... now read the user data from userRef
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me some advice. I finally realize what's wrong. I was trying to access the firebase realtime database that have security rules set on for authorization. Without login beforehand, there is no way for users or the apps to access the database. Therefore, I have to figure another way to access the database either by configure the rules or set my variables to SharedPreferences.

Comment: In that case, you should've gotten your warning `"Failed to read value."`. For a next question, please provide a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).

Comment: I'm quite new with android studio. I finally realized it after a while because I didn't filter out the tag used for the warning. My bad >0<'